# Delete the first half elements from stack of integer

Tags: java, stack

You are given a stack with n integers. You need to delete floor(n/2) elements from the bottom of the stack and print the remaining elements of the stack. The remaining elements should be printed in the order that they are inserted into the stack.

floor(3.5) will give the output as 3, greatest integer less than or equal to the input.
Input Format:
The first line of input is an integer n denoting the size of stack. The next line contains n space separated integers.
Output Format:
The remaining elements of the stack after removal of the required elements.
Example:
Stack(bottom -> top) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Output: [4, 5, 6]

Stack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
Output: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

Sample Input:
12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

Sample Output:
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

Sample input:
19
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

Sample Output:
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

Here my problem is my code passed test case 1 and test case 2 but in test case 3 where sample input is 19 there is should be printing as mentioned above output but my output came [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] its omitting 10th element and i dont know where is my error. So please help me in this

MY Code  -

```
import java.util.*;

public class DeleteElement {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        while (n-- > 0)
            stack.push(s.nextInt());
        deleteFirstHalf(stack, stack.size(), 0);
        System.out.println(stack);
    }

    static void deleteFirstHalf(Stack<Integer> stack, int n, int curr) {


        if(stack.empty() || curr == n) {
            return;
        }
        int x = stack.pop();

        deleteFirstHalf(stack, n, curr+1);

        if(curr<Math.floor(n/2)){
            stack.push(x);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note - Don't change the main() in my code.**

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried that with a Different Approach, where I created 2 different stacks `temp` and `temp1`, instead of recursively calling the function I had internal checks and printed the output at the end

```
static void deleteFirstHalf(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> temp1 = new Stack<Integer>();
    int i = stack.size();
    int dest = stack.size() / 2;
    while (i-- > dest) {
        int t = stack.pop();
        temp.push(t);
      }
    while (!temp.empty()) {
        int t = temp.pop();
        // System.out.print(i + " size");
        temp1.push(t);
    }
    System.out.print(temp1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bug comes from the fact that you're supposed to delete the bottom `floor(n/2)` elements, but instead you're keeping the top `floor(n/2)` elements. The reason it works for some test cases is that when n is even, keeping the top n/2 elements is the same as deleting the bottom n/2 elements. When n is odd, the code should keep one extra element.

The solution is to change `if (curr < Math.floor(n/2))` to `if (curr < n/2 + n%2)`. For one, you can drop the `Math.floor()`, since integer division does floor division anyway. The key difference is the addition of `n%2`. `n%2` evaluates to 0 when n is even, and 1 when n is odd. What this does is if n is odd, it will make the code keep one extra element. (in the case of the 3rd test case, it will keep 10 instead of deleting it) If n is even, `n%2` evaluates to 0, so the algorithm behaves the same as before.

Comment: no i have tried your way but if i use this then it fails my test case 1 and 2 u try it @a.deshpande012

Comment: @soumyaranjantripathy you're right, I missed a bug. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **curr<Math.floor(n/2)** try **n-curr > Math.floor(n/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (curr<Math.floor(n/2)) try (curr < n-Math.floor(n/2))